# Counting the posts of a loop (WP_Query)?

Tags: count

I tried this way to display NO of post:

```
<?php 
 $news_2 = new WP_Query( array ('post_type'=> 'jobs','posts_per_page'=> '10' , 'meta_key' => 'status_for_jobs','meta_value' => '1') );
  if ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { while ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { $news_2->the_post();

  $count = $news_2->post_count;

  ?>

    <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></li>



    <?php } } ?> <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

if the NO of post = 0 i need to display this :-

```
<?php 
 $news_2 = new WP_Query( array ('post_type'=> 'jobs','posts_per_page'=> '10' , 'meta_key' => 'status_for_jobs','meta_value' => '1') );
  if ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { while ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { $news_2->the_post();

  $count = $news_2->post_count;

  if ($count  == '0') {

  ?>
  <li><h3><a href="javascript:void(0)">No Post</a></h3></li>

  <?php
  } else {
  ?> 
    <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></li>

<?php  }  ?>

    <?php } } ?> <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But instead of the total of posts, I not getting any thing.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Hey, want to come back and weigh in on either of the 2 answers that have been provided to you?

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the WordPress Development model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 25):

Some additional information, no need to count the posts again, because [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) already did that for you. To clarify this, some information from the Class Reference of `WP_Query` as found in the »Properties« section:

> **$post_count**
>   The number of posts being displayed.
>
> **$found_posts**
>   The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters

What this means is

1. `$post_count` won't give you the total post count. It will most likely give you the number of posts you've defined with the `post_per_page` parameter, unless you've fewer posts than that or you're on the last page and there are only fewer posts left.
2. `$found_posts` can be used to get the total number of post related to a specific query. So there is no need to count them again.

In your case you can get the total count into your `$count` variable like this:

```
$count = $news_2->found_posts;
```

Besides of that @helgatheviking is right that, from what you've shown in your question, you don't need a extra conditional, but can just use the `have_posts()` method, in the conditional you already have, for that, like she suggested.

Comment: +1 for the found_posts property. You learn something new every day! :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to count the posts to show something different if no posts are found. You can just use the `else` part of your `if($news_2->have_posts())` check.

```
$news_2 = new WP_Query( array ('post_type'=> 'jobs','posts_per_page'=> '10' , 'meta_key' => 'status_for_jobs','meta_value' => '1') );

if ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { 

    while ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { 

        $news_2->the_post();

    ?> 

    <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></li>

<?php  } 

    } else { ?>

    <li><h3>No Post</h3></li>

    <?php } ?> 

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But if you truly need to count the number of posts returned, you can use

```
$count = count( $news_2->posts );
```