# How to make a sum of all posts displayed in a loop

Tags: posts, loop

I am trying to figure out a way to make a sum of all the posts displayed in a loop. For example:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :

$total_count = 1;
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
  echo $total_count;
endwhile;
endif;

?>
```

Returns: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Since there are 7 posts in my loop. However, I would like to make a sum of all those 1's in order to get 7 as a result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the posts of a loop (WP\_Query)?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/counting-the-posts-of-a-loop-wp-query)

Answer (score 2):

If `have_posts()` is `true`, there is a global `WP_Query` object available. And that has a post count already:

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    print $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post_count;
}
```

There is no need for a custom count.

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that this provides a total count of all posts. I would only like to count the posts in that specific loop.

Comment: @Johann You loop is going over all posts. Not sure what you mean? Maybe `found_posts`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$total_count = 0;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
  $total_count++;
endwhile;
endif;
echo 'Total Posts in loop:'. $total_count;
?>
```