# Query total number of posts

Tags: wp-query, filters, query

Using a search filter plugin. I am using to get the total number of posts that exist in the database

```
 $wp_query->found_posts
```

However, when a user filters the results on the page, this number changes according to how many posts are shown on the filter.

How could I get the static total number of posts which wouldn't change irrespective of what the user filters?

---

Update: This is my complete template code. I tried the answers below but couldn't make it work with my template. Any ideas?

```
if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    ?>
<ul id="florefs">
    <?php
    while ($query->have_posts())
    {
        $query->the_post();

        ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><i class="x-icon florex x-icon-angle-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php the_field('br_name'); ?></a>
        <div id="flosex"><span class="fimi"><?php the_field('br_category'); ?></span><span class="flag <?php echo strtolower(get_field('br_heritage')); ?>"></span><span class="fama"><?php the_field('br_heritage'); ?></span></div></li>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
    <div class="filhead">Page <?php echo $query->query['paged']; ?> of <?php echo $query->max_num_pages; ?></div>

    <div class="pagination">

        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( '<i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-left" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i> Previous page' ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next page <i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i>', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>

        <?php
            /* example code for using the wp_pagenavi plugin */
            if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
            {
                echo "<br />";
                wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );
            }
        ?>
    </div>

<div id="prasti"><span class="prase">PROBLEM HERE</span><span class="praso"><?php echo $query->found_posts; ?></span><span class="prasif">NEEDS</span><span class="prasi">CHANGE</span></div>

    <?php
}
else
{
    echo "There are no results for your selected criteria.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I get the static total number of posts which wouldn't change
>   irrespective of what the user filters?

You may be looking for `wp_count_posts()`: [Codex: WP COUNT POSTS](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts)

Example getting number of all published posts:

```
function get_all_them_posts(){
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts();

    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
    return $published_posts;
}
```

In template:

```
 <?php echo get_all_them_posts(); ?>
```

**For Custom Post Type:**

Functions.php:

```
function get_all_them_cpt_posts(){
    $post_type = 'your_post_type_slug_here';
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts( $post_type );

    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
    return $published_posts;
}
```

In template:

```
 <?php echo get_all_them_cpt_posts(); ?>
```

As noted by [Sam](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/115586/sam), and in [this older WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139622/118366), `$found_posts` is in reference to what the query is holding. `$post_count` is in reference to what is being displayed (often the number set in the posts_per_page parameter). I think `wp_count_posts()` is what you're looking for though.

---

### For Your Updated Code

(CPT version above)
Okay, it would be better to add the first code block to the functions.php of your theme (or child theme if you are using one). This:

```
function get_all_them_posts(){
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts();

    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
    return $published_posts;
}
```

Then where you wish to have the number of total posts in the template, replace:

```
<?php echo $query->found_posts; ?>
```

With:

```
<?php echo get_all_them_posts(); ?>
```

That line will call the function added to the functions.php
By doing it that way, you can use it in other template files without having to rewrite that function every time. 
I hope that helps!

Comment: please see my updated full code. I couldn't make it work for my template.

Comment: I have updated the answer with specifics to your updated question.

Comment: I tried your code, but it's returning 0

Comment: I tested it and it works as described above. Perhaps it is saying you have zero posts published? It is not checking drafts or private posts. Private would require an additional step.

Comment: No, the posts are published. Using found_posts I get the number 40.. Using this function i get 0. :(

Comment: What is before `if ( $query->have_posts() )`? Are there arguments passed to `new WP_Query` for any particular post_type? Just trying to make sure we are trying to count wordpress posts and not a custom post type or series of custom post types.

Comment: Actually it is a custom post type... That must be the issue.

Comment: yes, you have to declare that. Updating my answer...

Comment: added new function and echo under For Custom Post Type heading. That quick adjustment will hopefully work for you.

Comment: hmm ok but now it's the opposite. I get the number of all published posts in the custom post type. Not the ones selected in my search filter using the wp_query.. - found_posts gets the correct number, but that number is dynamic and changes when the user filters the results which I don't want to happen.

Comment: Right. wp_count_posts is going to returning the total in DB. I thought that was what your question is asking for. "static total number of posts" What you want is the original number of posts returned as determined by your query, and have that be available even when "filters" are applied. I'm guessing the filters are running a new query? I would have to see complete query and "filter" code to tell you where to set initial found_posts to a variable you might be able to echo.

Comment: yes... but this is getting too complicated bcs I have to analyse how the whole plugin works. Let's leave it for another day. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The $wp_query->$found_posts will change once you have filtered as the plugin might be changing the query so found_post will change each time.

```
$wp_query->$post_count
// The number of posts being displayed.
$wp_query->$found_posts
// The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters

// Total post amount in database
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
// Total post amount in database of custom post type called cars
// $count_posts = wp_count_posts('cars');
// Total count of the published amount of above
$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
```

Your code below should be

```
if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    ?>
<ul id="florefs">
    <?php
    while ($query->have_posts())
    {
        $query->the_post();

        ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><i class="x-icon florex x-icon-angle-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php the_field('br_name'); ?></a>
        <div id="flosex"><span class="fimi"><?php the_field('br_category'); ?></span><span class="flag <?php echo strtolower(get_field('br_heritage')); ?>"></span><span class="fama"><?php the_field('br_heritage'); ?></span></div></li>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
    <div class="filhead">Page <?php echo $query->query['paged']; ?> of <?php echo $query->max_num_pages; ?></div>

    <div class="pagination">

        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( '<i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-left" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i> Previous page' ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next page <i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i>', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>

        <?php
            /* example code for using the wp_pagenavi plugin */
            if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
            {
                echo "<br />";
                wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );
            }
        ?>
    </div>

<div id="prasti"><span class="prase">PROBLEM HERE</span><span class="praso"><?php echo wp_count_posts(); ?></span><span class="prasif">NEEDS</span><span class="prasi">CHANGE</span></div>

    <?php
}
else
{
    echo "There are no results for your selected criteria.";
}
?>
```

Comment: please see my updated full code. I couldn't make it work for my template.

Comment: I have changed your code to suit your needs.